# Angular only run forkJoin if response is not empty?

Tags: angular, response, fork-join, switchmap

I have a function for getting a list of notification rules. The problem is if no notification rule already exists then the function crashes. The line causing the issue is `response.rules.model.map((rule) => {` returns the error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

```
public getNotificationRuleItemsSet(): Observable<any[]> {
    const commonTxnList = this.configService.config.Notifications.TransactionTypeRules
        .CommonTxnList;
    const excludeTxnTypes = this.configService.config.Notifications.TransactionTypeRules
        .ExcludeTxnTypes;
    const showEffectForTxnTypes = this.configService.config.Notifications.TransactionTypeRules
        .ShowEffectForTxnTypes;

    return this.getNotificationRules().pipe(
        take(1),
        tap((response: any) => {
            if (response.txntypes) {
                this.txnTypes = response.txntypes.model;
            }
            if (response.accounts) {
                this.accounts = response.accounts.model;
            }
        }),
        switchMap((response: any) => {
            return forkJoin([
                forkJoin(
                    response.txntypes.model.map((txntype) => {
                        let commonIndex = commonTxnList.indexOf(txntype.txntypename);
                        let excludeIndex = excludeTxnTypes.indexOf(txntype.txntypename);
                        let showEffectIndex = showEffectForTxnTypes.indexOf(
                            txntype.txntypename
                        );

                        let item: INotificationTxnType = {
                            id: txntype.id,
                            txntypename: txntype.txntypename,
                            locname: txntype.locname,
                            shortList: commonIndex >= 0 ? true : false,
                            exclude: excludeIndex >= 0 ? true : false,
                            showEffect: showEffectIndex >= 0 ? true : false,
                        };
                        return of(item);
                    })
                ),
                of(response.accounts.model),
                forkJoin(
                    response.rules.model.map((rule) => {
                        switch (rule.type) {
                            case NotificationType.Account: {
                                return this.getOneRuleItem_Account(rule).pipe(take(1));
                            }
                            case NotificationType.TxnType: {
                                return this.getOneRuleItem_TxnType(rule).pipe(take(1));
                            }
                            case NotificationType.Currency: {
                                return this.getOneRuleItem_Currency(rule).pipe(take(1));
                            }
                            default: {
                                return of();
                            }
                        }
                    })
                ),
            ]);
        })
    );
}
```

If no rules are returned then it doesn't need to run the section of code below. Is there a way to run a check within this function like`if(response.rules.length > 0)`then only run this section of code?

```
forkJoin(
                    response.rules.model.map((rule) => {
                        switch (rule.type) {
                            case NotificationType.Account: {
                                return this.getOneRuleItem_Account(rule).pipe(take(1));
                            }
                            case NotificationType.TxnType: {
                                return this.getOneRuleItem_TxnType(rule).pipe(take(1));
                            }
                            case NotificationType.Currency: {
                                return this.getOneRuleItem_Currency(rule).pipe(take(1));
                            }
                            default: {
                                return of();
                            }
                        }
                    })
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use RxJS [`iif`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/iif) function. Also instead of `of()` you could use the RxJS [`EMPTY`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/const/EMPTY) constant. That way the outer `forkJoin` will still emit but you don't get `undefined` in the subscription. Ofcourse if you wish to have `undefined` in the subscription you could continue using `of()`.

Try the following

```js
iif(
  () => !!response.rules && !!response.rules.model,  // <-- use `forkJoin` only if `response.rules` is defined
  forkJoin(
    response.rules.model.map((rule) => {
      switch (rule.type) {
        case NotificationType.Account: {
          return this.getOneRuleItem_Account(rule).pipe(take(1));
        }
        case NotificationType.TxnType: {
          return this.getOneRuleItem_TxnType(rule).pipe(take(1));
        }
        case NotificationType.Currency: {
          return this.getOneRuleItem_Currency(rule).pipe(take(1));
        }
        default: {
          return EMPTY;
        }
      }
    })
  )
)
```

I've included the condition for both inner `forkJoin`s.

```js
public getNotificationRuleItemsSet(): Observable <any[]> {
  ...

  return this.getNotificationRules().pipe(
    take(1),
    tap((response: any) => {
      if (response.txntypes) {
        this.txnTypes = response.txntypes.model;
      }
      if (response.accounts) {
        this.accounts = response.accounts.model;
      }
    }),
    switchMap((response: any) => {
      return forkJoin([
        iif(
          () => !!response.txntypes && !!response.txntypes.model,
          forkJoin(
            response.txntypes.model.map((txntype) => {
              let commonIndex = commonTxnList.indexOf(txntype.txntypename);
              let excludeIndex = excludeTxnTypes.indexOf(txntype.txntypename);
              let showEffectIndex = showEffectForTxnTypes.indexOf(
                txntype.txntypename
              );

              let item: INotificationTxnType = {
                id: txntype.id,
                txntypename: txntype.txntypename,
                locname: txntype.locname,
                shortList: commonIndex >= 0 ? true : false,
                exclude: excludeIndex >= 0 ? true : false,
                showEffect: showEffectIndex >= 0 ? true : false,
              };
              return of(item);
            })
          )
        ), 
        of (response.accounts.model),
        iif(
          () => !!response.rules && !!response.rules.model,
          forkJoin(
            response.rules.model.map((rule) => {
              switch (rule.type) {
                case NotificationType.Account: {
                  return this.getOneRuleItem_Account(rule).pipe(take(1));
                }
                case NotificationType.TxnType: {
                  return this.getOneRuleItem_TxnType(rule).pipe(take(1));
                }
                case NotificationType.Currency: {
                  return this.getOneRuleItem_Currency(rule).pipe(take(1));
                }
                default: {
                  return EMPTY;
                }
              }
            })
          )
        ),
      ]);
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: Still getting same error - Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: In that case may be `rules` is defined, but `models` isn't. Extend the condition to `() => !!response.rules && !!response.rules.model`. Or please provide a better picture of your object. I've updated the answer.